# How to load database content using Select box without button & javaScript

Tags: php, mysql, select, textbox

I'm making an administrative page for a website, for editing front-end contents. I don't want to use JavaScript, I want to make it with raw PHP.

The thing is: The user will choose a page from the select box, and the contents according to the page will be loaded into two text boxes. Then the user will edit them on text boxes and update the contents using an update button.

(there is no submit button for the select box, I want 'onselect' data content load)

I need, the user will simply select a page, no button to be pressed then and the content will be loaded. I want not to deploy JavaScript for this. Is it possible using raw PHP? Any suggestion?

Comment: have you tried anything? where did you got any problem?

Comment: I know I din't share any codes. I wanted to share a screen-shot, but as a new comer, I don't have the privilege to upload images. Ok, I got some answers and thought. Let's try first, then I'll share much inshALLAH. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side programming language. You can't really affect the client side directly, only indirectly through forms etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept your users may have to use the enter key, which will submit the form, you're fine.

But you can't have an action occurring on a select, without even using the enter key, without javascript.

Note that the requirement to not use javascript, especially for an administrative tool, doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks dystroy for your to-the-point review. I know it's possible using javaScript, AJAX. But I'm a new student of PHP, so I want to explore PHP as much as I can. That's why I'm searching for solutions using PHP (even the solution is present in a good way with other scripts). I hope you would like such interests.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible with raw PHP, but I do not recommend it.

You can put the select-box inside a

```
<form action="targetFile.php" method="GET">
```

To submit the form without a submit-button, you can use:

```
<select name="sel" onChange="this.form.submit()">
```

When the form is submitted, the browser loads the site "targetFile.php"
On this site, you can use php to set the text-box content:

```
<input type="text" value="
    <?php
        if($_GET['sel'] == 0) echo "content1";
        else echo "content2";
    ?>
">
```

If you want to load the content dynamically (without realoading a site) you have to use Javascript and maybe Ajax.

Comment: are you aware that `this.form.submit()` **is** javascript ?

Comment: I think this is a solution I's looking for. I'm going apply it, and I'll let you know. And of course, thanks very much that you understood me without any screen-shot or codes. :) Thanks very much.

Comment: oops! if dystroy is right, and I think he is right, cz it's not working here. I think, eakron (3rd answer) is right: PHP has no such power doing this without scripts.

Comment: yeah, right. This uses javascript. In order to not use javascript you will have to use a submit-button because this would be the only way to submit the form. As @eakron said, php can't be used on the client side and it can't react on user-inputs. (You would need JS or Forms+Submit-Button)